# working with Openssl on servers hosted on AWS EC2

Tags: security-certificate, amazon-aws, openssl

I am new to AWS and someone who configured things on AWS has set up the following on the EC2 Dashboard for production(2 instances which are load balanced) and qa(1 instance) servers.

[image]

**What I want to do :**

For two servers I want to generate a Customer Signing Request as I want to send it over to CA authority to obtain domain validated certificate from them. In order to do that is there any command line interface I would have to use on AWS to run some commands and generate CSR? I have openssl package on my windows machine right now but since its no way related to AWS, I doub't it would make sense working on it to generate CSR. Please correct me if I am wrong?

Please advise if there are any other steps associated with it as I am very new to AWS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter where the CSR is generated as long as its generated in a compatible format, i.e OpenSSL, IIS, Microsoft Exchange and Keytool.

It's extremely common for people to use different devices to create their SSL CERT. You can even use 3rd party online websites to [generate the SSL cert](https://www.digicert.com/csr-creation.htm), meaning you don't need to run anything from the commandline. Another popular choice is to use cPanel to generate the CSR, you don't even need to use cPanel to host that website.

Comment: Thanks. By any chance you know where can I configure the domain validated certificates after obtaining it from CA? Looking at the instances shown above, I believe I would need to configure at some place for the 3 instances (2 for production and 1 for QA) ? Please advise.

Comment: @John, please post separate questions as separate questions, after searching the site to verify that they haven't already been answered.